# Why is the C++ standard library Container function empty() marked as [[nodiscard]]?

Tags: c++, c++20, nodiscard

It seems like [`empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty) is the only function that has been marked as [`nodiscard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard).

Other similar functions like [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) have not.

Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I would expect that more functions will be marked `[[nodiscard]]` in the future.

However, `empty` is traditionally a point of confusion for new users. They think that it's a verb, and that it will remove all the elements of a container (the correct call here is `clear`).

So marking `empty` as `[[nodiscard]]` catches all the places where people call it expecting it to do something to the container (instead of just returning `size() == 0`)

Comment: Updating a few million line codebase hit this about 5 times.  Mostly other containers with `Empty` translated to std containers at some point.  Annoyingly, at least one was a mandatory failure (ie, the error was relied upon by the code).  Sigh.

Comment: While I hope that great library implementers mark many more functions as ```[[nodiscard]]```, I wouldn't expect much more in terms of the standard doing so.  Technically, it has no normative effect, and practically speaking, the more time the committee spends debating which functions should be marked ```[[nodiscard]```, the less time the committee spends on other desirable features.